# Getting error [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem in making a simple test in javascript. This is a quick example. Each question's div id is incremented in the html code.

HTML

```
<form action="#">
    <div id="q1">
        <label>Q. ABCD</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1">A</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2">B</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="3">C</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="4">D</label>
    </div>
    ....
    ....
    <input type="button" value="Click to Submit" onClick="result();">
</form>
```

JS (say for 10 questions)

```
function result() {
    var answer = new Array();
    for(var i=1; i<11 ; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById("q" + i).getElementsByTagName("input") != undefined) {
            answer[i] = document.getElementById("q" + i).getElementsByTagName("input");
        }
        else {
            answer[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    console.log(answer);
}
```

I am getting an error [object HTMLCollection] every time I submit the code. How should I do this so that I can get the value of each answer given inside the array and if someone doesn't answer any question, the array must get 0 value at its place instead of undefined. I need a pure JS and HTML solution.

Comment: `document.write` is not ever going to be part of the solution

Comment: I just need to check that the array is getting right values or not. That is why i wrote document.write.

Comment: I guess the question is, what do you expect the `result` function to actually do - the error is because you are using document.write - just don't do that for a start

Comment: use console.log instead

Comment: If there are not elements then `getElementsByTagName` does not return undefined, it returns an empty array. Anyway, your code is doing exactly what you told it to do--return a list of elements. Why would think that somebody would magically pick the values out of the elements for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
function result() {
    var answer = new Array();
    // there is no answer 0
    answer[0] = 'unused';
    for(var i=1; i<11 ; i++) {
        // check if the id exists first
        var container = document.getElementById("q" + i);
        if(container) {
            // get the selected radio checkbox
            var input = container.querySelector("input:checked");
            // if there's one selected, save it's value
            if(input) {
                answer[i] = input.value;
            }
            else {
                answer[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(answer);
}
```

a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dtpLjru1/

Comment: Yes this worked! thanks. By the way please tell me why you used answer[0] = 'unused'; without it i am getting exact array that i needed.

Comment: that doesn't have to be there - it'd be `undefined` otherwise - Array indexes in javascript start at 0

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to store the HTML collection by using getElementByTagName(). This method will return all the Tags with the name of "input", so total of 4 tags as per the code above.

**Instead of that, you can modify your code like below.**

***Assuming, you want to store "1" in case radio button is checked. else 0***

> ```
> function result() {
>         var answer = new Array();
>         for (var i = 1; i <= 4 ; i++) {
>             if (document.getElementById("q" + i).getElementsByTagName("input") != undefined) {
>                 answer[i] = document.getElementById("q" + i).checked ? 1 : 0;
>             }
>             else {
>                 answer[i] = 0;
>             }
>         }
>         console.log(answer);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Have not tested the code, How about we do this ?

```
function result() {
    var answer = new Array();
    for(i=1; i<11 ; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById("q" + i).getElementsByTagName("input") != undefined) {
            document.write( document.getElementById("q" + i).getElementsByTagName("input") );
        }
        else {
            document.write(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting [object HTMLCollection] error 10 times. Thanks for the reply but its not working either.

Comment: agree with you but what if he has to return that array...problem here is answer become two dimension array i.e. array with in array ...